# objective-c determine image resolution

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, macos

For some reason I could not figure it out.

```
UIImage *image = //initialize with some image, etc.
```

Is there a way to get the resolution of image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean the width/height?

```
CGFloat width = image.size.width
CGFloat height = image.size.height
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the dimensions of the image, you can use the `size` property on a `UIImage`.  The DPI (resolution/scale) can be found through the `scale` attribute.  Here is a reference from [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The scale factor of the image. (read-only)
>
> ```
> @property (nonatomic,readonly) CGFloat scale
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If you load an image from a file whose name includes the @2x modifier, the scale is set to 2.0. If the filename does not include the modifier but is in the PNG or JPEG format and has an associated DPI value, a corresponding scale factor is computed and reflected in this property. You can also specify an explicit scale factor when initializing an image from a Core Graphics image. All other images are assumed to have a scale factor of 1.0.
>
> If you multiply the logical size of the image (stored in the size property) by the value in this property, you get the dimensions of the image in pixels.
>
> For normal images, the scale will be 1.0.  For JPG/PNG images, the scale may be different.  Also, if your image name has '@2x' before the extension, UIImage assumes that its scale is 2.0.